# Direct and Indirect speech

Tags: british-english, speech, indirect-speech, narration

What would be the indirect speech for this sentence: Mina said, "Let's go for a walk".
In my opinion it should be 'Mina suggested that they should go for a walk' but according to my book it is 'Mina suggested that they go for a walk'. Which one is correct?

Comment: Either one works.

Comment: Your book matches "go for a walk" in "Let's go for a walk" and "that they go for a walk." When you add *should*, it is closer to "Mina said, 'We should go for a walk.' "